# Why is this function working on second click only?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple function that hides text on click. However it only works on the second click. I tried rewording the conditional statement but nothing has worked so far. jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Montinyek/293hmpu1/18/

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
let hello = document.getElementById('hello');

function test() {
  if (hello.style.display !== 'block') {
    hello.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    hello.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

btn.addEventListener('click', test)
```

```html
<div id='hello'>
  hello
</div>

<div id='btn'>
  button
</div>
```

Comment: hint: on first click `hello.style.display !== 'block'` is TRUE - so you're adding a style to `hello` that make no difference to how it is being displayed, since a div's "natural" display value is block - setting it to `block` does nothing .... try `hello.style.display === 'none'` for the condition instead

Comment: In addition to @Bravo's comment, the `element.style.display` is empty on first click, because it has not been set yet. If you add `style="display:block;"` to the `hello` div in your html, it will work on first click. Also, style properties are always strings, so you can use simple  `!=`

Comment: You could use `getComputedStyle(hello)` instead of `hello.style`. Then it will get the style from CSS instead of the attribute.

Comment: @vanowm thank you, but why doesn't it work if i set the display using CSS? Looks like it only works if i set "display: block" inline

Comment: Because `Element.style` only referencing to style attribute, if you need get actual css value , you'll need use `getComputedStyle(Element)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the start nothing has set the style so the test !==‘block’ will be true. And you then set the style to block so it needs another click to get it to none.

If you set things the other way round it will work because the style is not set to none so you then immediately set it to none.

The confusion often seems to arise because setting the style properties is not there initially, ie not set until you set them.

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
let hello = document.getElementById('hello');

function test() {
  if (hello.style.display !== 'none') {
    hello.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    hello.style.display = 'block';
  }
}

btn.addEventListener('click', test)
```

```html
<div id='hello'>
  hello
</div>

<div id='btn'>
  button
</div>
```